# With Boost.spirit, is there any way to pass additional argument to attribute constructor?

Tags: constructor, attributes, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Maybe a noob question, I've a piece of code like this:

```
struct S {
    S() {...}
    S(int v) {
        // ...
    }
};
qi::rule<const char*, S(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ip=qi::int_parser<S()>();
qi::rule<const char*, std::vector<S>(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> parser %= ip % ',';
...
```

Rules above can work, but the code breaks if S constructors require additional parameters, such as:

```
struct S {
    S(T t) {...}
    S(T t, int v) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

I've spent days to find solution, but no luck so far.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way, but you can probably explicitely initialize things:

```
qi::rule<It, optional<S>(), Skipper> myrule;

myrule %= 
       qi::eps [ _val = phoenix::construct<S>(42) ] >>
       int_parser<S()>;
```

However, since you are returning it from the int_parser, my intuition says that default-initialization should be appropriate (or perhaps the type S doesn't have a single, clear, responsibility?).

### **Edit**

In response to the comment, it looks like you want this:

```
T someTvalue;    

myrule = qi::int_ 
   [ qi::_val = phx::construct<S>(someTvalue, qi::_1) ];
```

Or, if `someTvalue` is a variable outside the grammar constructor, and may change value during execution of the parser (and it lives long enough!), you could do

```
myrule = qi::int_ 
   [ qi::_val = phx::construct<S>(phx::ref(someTvalue), qi::_1) ];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I was using qi::int, not int_parser.
For my understanding, phoenix can delay initialization, but cannot add an additional parameter, where to put the argument "T t" then?

Comment: In my sample, it goes inside the () for `construct<S>(...)` (multiple parameters are possible)

Comment: But S cannot receive the int parsed by next rule then. I still don't see how to receive both T and parsed int to correctly construct a S instance.